# find text in without match case on rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms

This code works but its find only match case. But I need a none match case text to find. I am so used ""rich text box finds.none"" but my code find only like a match case.
i have a code for none match case.

```
    using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.ComponentModel;
       using System.Data;
       using System.Drawing;
       using System.Text;
       using System.Windows.Forms;

       namespace Notepad
         {
            public partial class Find : Form
              {
               int k = 0;
        string text;
        static int curr = 0;
        public Find()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // string[] k;
          //  k[0] = Form1.textBox1.Lines.GetValue(0);
            if (Form1.textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not find " + textBox1.Text, "Notepad");
            }
            else
            {
                text = StoreData.getAllText();
                if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
                {
                    for (int i = curr; i <= text.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (curr + textBox1.Text.Length <= text.Length)
                        {
                            if (text.Substring(curr, textBox1.Text.Length) == textBox1.Text)
                            {
                                Form1.textBox1.Select(curr, textBox1.Text.Length);
                                curr++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                curr++;
                                if (curr == text.Length)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Can not find " + textBox1.Text, "Notepad");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // k to able the current continuted not in the start
                    if (k == 0)
                    {
                        k = 1;
                        curr = text.Length - textBox1.Text.Length;
                        StoreData.setCurrent(curr);
                    }
                    for (int i = StoreData.getCurrent(); i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        // if (curr <= 0)
                        //{
                        if (text.Substring(curr, textBox1.Text.Length) == textBox1.Text)
                        {
                            Form1.textBox1.Select(curr, 1);
                           // Form1.textBox1.Find(textBox1.Text, curr, Form1.textBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);

                            curr--;
                            StoreData.setCurrent(curr);
                            break;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            curr--;
                            if (curr == 0)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Can not find " + textBox1.Text, "Notepad");
                            }
                        }
                        // }
                        StoreData.setCurrent(curr);
                    }
                }
                text = Form1.textBox1.Text;
                StoreData.setAllText(Form1.textBox1.Text);
                Form1.textBox1.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {
                curr = 0;
                k = 0;
                button1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what is your question and what you're trying to achieve. Please edit your question to add more details. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the string.Compare, with the IgnoreCase flag set to true.  That should give you the compare NoCase result I believe you are looking for.

```
using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace Notepad
     {
        public partial class Find : Form
          {
           int k = 0;
    string text;
    static int curr = 0;
    public Find()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // string[] k;
      //  k[0] = Form1.textBox1.Lines.GetValue(0);
        if (Form1.textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not find " + textBox1.Text, "Notepad");
        }
        else
        {
            text = StoreData.getAllText();
            if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                for (int i = curr; i <= text.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (curr + textBox1.Text.Length <= text.Length)
                    {
                        if (string.Compare(text.Substring(curr, textBox1.Text.Length), textBox1.Text, true)==0)
                        {
                            Form1.textBox1.Select(curr, textBox1.Text.Length);
                            curr++;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            curr++;
                            if (curr == text.Length)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Can not find " + textBox1.Text, "Notepad");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // k to able the current continuted not in the start
                if (k == 0)
                {
                    k = 1;
                    curr = text.Length - textBox1.Text.Length;
                    StoreData.setCurrent(curr);
                }
                for (int i = StoreData.getCurrent(); i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    // if (curr <= 0)
                    //{
                    if (string.Compare(text.Substring(curr, textBox1.Text.Length), textBox1.Text,true)==0)
                    {
                        Form1.textBox1.Select(curr, 1);
                       // Form1.textBox1.Find(textBox1.Text, curr, Form1.textBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);

                        curr--;
                        StoreData.setCurrent(curr);
                        break;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        curr--;
                        if (curr == 0)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Can not find " + textBox1.Text, "Notepad");
                        }
                    }
                    // }
                    StoreData.setCurrent(curr);
                }
            }
            text = Form1.textBox1.Text;
            StoreData.setAllText(Form1.textBox1.Text);
            Form1.textBox1.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            curr = 0;
            k = 0;
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Error 2 The name 'CompareOptions' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Notepad\Notepad\Notepad\Find.cs 73 103 Notepad

Comment: Bah, sorry I was originally using the CompareOrdinal, but switched my code to CompareCase.  I will update the code.